# how to populate the value from input field into dropdown on page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my html for a dropdown :

```
<select id="esc-options">
 <option class="esc">name1</option>
 <option class="esc">name2</option>
 <option class="esc">name3</option>
</select>
```

I have an input field as below that Im trying to get its value populated in the above dropdown.

```
<td class="input">
        <input class="name" id="nameInput"/></td>
```

I'm trying to save the value from this input field into the dropdown on page redirect. So my current input field is having the url: `localhost:8000/#/create/` and my dropdown is using annother page called: `localhost:8000/#/newpolicy/`.
when I redirect from /create/ page to the /newpolicy/ page i should be able to save the value in the dropdown that i entered in the input field.

I'm storing the value in the cookie:

```
nameEsc = $(".name").val()
                $.cookie "nameEsc", nameEsc
```

Here is what i'm trying to code:

```
if $.cookie('redirect')
{ opts = $("#esc-options")
opts.append "<option value=\"" + nameEsc + "\">" + nameEsc + "</option>"
}
```

Does anyone have ideas over this??

Comment: are you using http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Comment: Yes, im using the plugin

Comment: I think you are not using the correct syntax as mentioned in the documentation